# Given two segments in 3D, compute closest point between them using CGAL

Tags: c++, computational-geometry, cgal

Given two segments in 3D in CGAL, I would like to compute the closest points between one segment and another. These two segment may be anywhere in space.

I have looked in CGAL and there is a function which computes distance between both segments (https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Kernel_23/group__squared__distance__grp.html), and with that I guess I could create two spheres and compute the intersection between them, but this seems slow and cumbersome.

Is there something out of the box?

Comment: [The shortest line between two lines in 3D](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=The+shortest+line+between+two+lines+in+3D)

Comment: Sorry, can you develop a bit more? I am not sure I understand

Comment: Do you mean line segments or lines ? (Always the same ambiguity.)

Comment: segments, the chunk of a line between two points :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say, there are no out-of-the-box way in the CGAL library **to see** two points, defining the shortest segment between two line segments in 3D. I'm saying "to see" because these two points are *actually computed* deeply inside the `CGAL::squared_distance` function, then the distance between them is calculated, and then these two points are discarded.

If you really need these two points you can modify the  `Distance_3/Segment_3_Segment_3.h` file and add a function with an additional argument:

```
template <class K>
inline
typename K::FT
squared_distance(const Segment_3<K>& seg1,
                 const Segment_3<K>& seg2,
                 Segment_3<K>& res)
{
  // ... modifications
}
```

Of course you'll need to modify other code in this file as well.

Comment: I was actually expecting these two points to be computed to compute that distance

Comment: I will asked in CGAL github if it make sense to make this changes to the library

Comment: Yes, good idea. May be, a new global function `shortest_segment(obj1, obj2)` will make sense for them

Answer (score 0):

**Analytically:**

You want to minimize the function

```
(A + p AB - C - q CD)²
```

under inequality constraints `0 ≤ p ≤ 1` and `0 ≤ q ≤ 1`.

By differentiation, you get a linear system of 2 equations in the 2 unknowns `p` and `q`. After resolution, if these values fall in the allowed range, you are done.

```
p AB² - q AB.CD = AB.AC
p CD.AB - q CD² = CD.AC
```

Otherwise, you need to saturate one constraint (`p=0`, `p=1`, `q=0` or `q=1`) and check if the other parameter is in range. (Endpoint to segment distances.)

Otherwise, you saturate both constraints (4 combinations). (Endpoint to endpoint distances.)

Finally, you keep the feasible solution that yields the smallest distance.

If the two segments are parallel or collinear, there can be an infinity of solution points.

---

**Addendum:**

WLOG, `AB.CD ≤ 0` (otherwise swap two endpoints). Then then from the inequalities we draw

```
- AB.CD ≤ p AB² - q AB.CD ≤ AB²
- AB.CD ≤ p AB.CD - q CD² ≤ CD²
```

which directly gives us the condition for existence of a segment-segment solution:

```
- AB.CD ≤ AB.AC ≤ AB²
- AB.CD ≤ CD.AC ≤ CD²
```

We get the conditions for endpoint-segment solutions by substituting `0` or `1` for `p` or `q`.

Comment: This is helpful, but I haven't asked for a mathematical derivation to implemented my own, to do so I could just grab the Real Time Collision Detection book. I was asking an out of the box solution using CGAL

Comment: IHow is my question offtopic? Is about help with a C++ library... I didnt asked about math, but about the usage of CGAL